# Short story about Christmas retail season running the entire year

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Every year, when the retail stores start putting out Christmas displays earlier and earlier, I think back to this story. This year, I want to track it down.

It was in a paperback short story collection. I'd say the story is at minimum 20+ years old. I had often picked up secondhand sci-fi short story compilations, so it could easily be 50+ years.

I don't recall any particular futuristic technology, It was if the story was written in the contemporary period, except that that the Christmas retail season ran all year long.

The main character was a male employee in a store. He's concerned that it's summer and they're behind in their Christmas sales projections.

He is attracted to a young woman that works at the store. As he gets to know her, he finds that she does not seem all that interested in Christmas.

At one point in the story, he dresses like Santa and visits her house with presents for her younger brother. It causes consternation among her family, especially her father.

The main character discovers that the family is religious and doesn't celebrate the material side of Christmas and I believe the story ends with the main character attending a church service with the woman's family.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about the collection? For example, if the other stories were more overtly science fictional?

Comment: There is something like this in "Great Joy" by Ursula K. LeGuin, collected in ther anthology _Changing Planes_. But there's no religious redemptive ending because LeGuin didn't roll like that.

Comment: @user888379 Yeah, it was definitely sci-fi (It's the only books I ever purchase) but I was starting to doubt myself as I typed out the description. I would pick up used sci-fi short story collections all over the place, so I've got no idea of the period of the book or what else was in it. I'm pretty sure it wasn't a Christmas anthology.

Comment: Thank you, @Valorum for helping me not feel crazy.

Comment: @Spencer, I can't find any details on "Great Joy" by Ursula K. LeGuin (aside from it appearing in "Changing Planes"), but from your comments, I'm guessing it's not that story, but I'll keep digging.

Comment: @Spencer, I certainly don't remember the "wrapper" for the stories, and I don't remember the cover.

People from Earth practice interplanary travel either out of boredom at the airport or as tourists who want to spend their holidays on a particular plane. When the stories focus on them instead of the natives of the other planes, it is done for Aesopian purposes.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/ChangingPlanes

Comment: @user888379, Per Andrew's answer, the story was written in 1956.

As a child in the 70's, I remember that Christmas officially DID NOT start until after Thanksgiving. (I  I remember, the stores were closed on Friday to set up for Christmas.)

When Pohl wrote the story in 1956, I'll bet the idea Christmas before Thanksgiving was a totally alien concept.

Comment: I don't know what the ramifications of the question being "closed", as I received the answer that I was looking for.

For what it's worth, I searched this site and couldn't find the original answer. Frankly, I think the original question is unclear, and doesn't represent the gist of the story as well as my question, so I hope this question remains searchable for the next person.

Comment: @Mister3 On SFF:SE, if two story-identification questions are verifiably about the same story, one of the questions (usually the one posted later) is closed as a duplicate. This exists to help people who come along later searching for the same story.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*Happy Birthday Dear Jesus*](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57228) by Fred Pohl, in the same general continuity as the "Space Merchants" novels. It's discussed [here](https://sfshortstories.com/?p=2117)

> The main character was a male employee in a store. He's concerned that
> it's summer and they're behind in their Christmas sales projections.

**[The story] begins with the story’s narrator, Mr Martin, recruiting a young woman called Lilymary Hargreave for his department at Heinemann’s store. Her job is to gift-wrap and label shoppers’ Christmas purchases, and it’s here where we get the first dose of satire (apart an earlier mention that this Christmas rush is happening in early September)**

> He is attracted to a young woman that works at the store. As he gets
> to know her, he finds that she does not seem all that interested in
> Christmas.

**The rest of the story sees Martin romantically pursue Lilymary, which provides a clash-of-cultures situation between him and the family, who have just returned to the United States after a long time in Borneo as religious missionaries.**

> At one point in the story, he dresses like Santa and visits her house
> with presents for her younger brother. It causes consternation among
> her family, especially her father.

**Then, when he later arranges for the visit of a Santa Claus and the Elves sales team to the house, the relationship breaks down completely.**

> The main character discovers that the family is religious and doesn't
> celebrate the material side of Christmas and I believe the story ends
> with the main character attending a church service with the woman's
> family.

**He eventually succeeds when he tracks them down to a church service, prays with Lilymary, and then gets religion.**

It's been collected many times, including in **The Best of Frederik Pohl**

Comment: That's it! Thanks @Andrew!

This is the cover that I have:
https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/the-best-of-frederik-pohl_frederik-pohl/736193

Comment: Interesting. I'm sure I've read the story, but it certainly didn't make much of an impression on me.